# FT231XS FTDI USB UART self-powered circuit

Tags: uart, usb-device, ftdi

I haven't been able to find a full example of a self-powered [FT231XS](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/163/DS_FT231X-13571.pdf) circuit. I was hoping to get feedback on what I have put together from studying the datasheet (any glaring issues?):

[image: My self-powered (3v circuit)]

**3v3_RUN** is my 3v power rail from my separate regulator

I was a little unsure about connecting **VCC** to **VCCIO**, **3V3OUT**, and **RESET**. From reading the datasheet it sounds like you need to do this if powering the FTDI chip via 3v. If I had say a 5v supply, I think you would not connect **VCC** to the other power pins. Wondering if I'm interpreting this correctly.

I'm also wondering what would happen if the 3v supply were turned off, but USB was still plugged in.

FYI I'm not a professional, EE is a hobby for me.

**Datasheet description of power pins:**
[image: Datasheet description of power pins]

**Datasheet self-powered diagram:**
[image: Datasheet self-powered diagram]

**Datasheet wording regarding self-powered usage:**
[image: Datasheet wording regarding self-powered usage]

Answer (score 1):

The schematic looks OK, although you could add maybe 1 more small bypass cap (should work anyway tho).

Your device is not in self-powered mode. "Self-powered" implies that it uses its own 3.3V regulator output to power its own logic - VCCIO. But you supply all power externally. So it's not self-powered.

VCC is just an input for the 3.3V regulator in the chip. 3V3OUT is the output of that regulator, that powers the chip itself via VCCIO, all its functions - logic. It's made that way specifically to be able to power 3.3V logic with USB 5V.

As for USB sending something while the IC is unpowered, you can't communicate with unpowered device. It won't be detected by USB, so you can't send anything to it. There will be no enumeration, completely nothing. Whether it's safe for the device to plug it into USB lines, which are not at 0V idle, while the chip has no power, is an open question. I quickly glanced through the datasheet, didn't find anything solid about that, which should mean it's not expected and there is no guarantee it will work reliably. Unless it's explicitly specified, it can be considered out of spec and undesirable.

Comment: So if I was powering VCC using a 5v supply that is separate from USB 5v, I would not connect VCC with the other power pins (like the self-powered schematic shows), this would be considered self-powered? What is confusing is that the self-powered schematic labels VCC as supporting 3.3-5v. But that conflicts with "If VCC is 3V3 then 3V3OUT must also be driven with 3V3 input". I'm basically just trying to understand if I was right to base my design on the self-powered schematic + altering it based on using 3v for VCC. Seems like yes based on your response. Saying its not self-powered surprised me

Comment: VCC is 3.3V-5V so that you can actually choose the voltage, and you give power to 3V3OUT just to keep the internal regulator off (how exactly it works internally, we don't know, so it's my educated guess). It is considered self-powered if VCCIO is powered by the output of 3V3OUT (while in your case 3V3OUT is inactive and 3.3V is supplied externally). Your design is based on non-self-powered design, and it looks fine to me as long as the device is powered when USB is plugged in. You can also power it from USB of course, then you'll have to make it self-powered (5V VCC-> 3V3OUT->VCCIO)

Comment: This is confusing because what you are describing as self powered sounds a lot like the bus powered schematic (6.1). In that example VCC is powered by 5v from USB, and VCCIO is connected to 3V3OUT. Forgive my ignorance, I'm probably overlooking something.

Comment: It's basically the same thing. Check 6.1 and 6.2. In both, VCC is separate from 3V3OUT. The only difference is in where VCC voltage comes from, but the logic with powering VCCIO with internal voltage regulator 3V3OUT is the same. USB also uses VBUS_SENSE signal on CBUS pin, seemingly as enable signal. But in both VCC voltage does not power VCCIO directly.